# showing different views to different users in sharepoint 2010

Tags: sharepoint-2010

I have a list in a sharepoint site and i want to show different views of the same list to different groups of users. Is it possible in sharepoint 2010?

Answer (score 4):

I don't believe you can assign a view to an audience through default functionality.

There is a solution though. Each list view is assigned its own unique url.  You can take the URL's for each view and add it to the Navigation bar.  You can then assign an audience to each of the links.  This will allow a member of that particular audience to have a link that will take them directly to the desired view.

**DISCLAIMER:** This should not be used as a form of security.  I believe if someone has access to the list they will be able to change to any view that they want.

Comment: +1 for the disclaimer. Lists cannot have column-based security out of the box. Therefore hiding columns in views would simply be security by obscurity.

Answer (score 0):

For anyone else finding this, you can also add multiple views as webparts and target them by audience. I have not noticed any performance issues doing this. The only problem I have had is that once the webpart takes the view it does not update when the view parameters change.

Answer (score 0):

I achieved this by creating another view. The default view which is the All documents view had users able to see only documents they have uploaded. Then the other view i did a view permission to show/hide view  to specific users